# BoxOfficeMojo refusing connections from Selenium. Works fine with beautiful soup so it's not the actual connection

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter

Anyone know what's going on? I'm about to throw my computer out the window. Beautiful soup is working fine with the same page, so I know it's not the connection. And I've tried putting `WebDriverWait` and `time.sleep(10)` in between every line - after the delay, the same error comes up.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time, os
import pandas as pd
import re

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

chromedriver = "/usr/bin/chromedriver" # path to the chromedriver executable
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver

i = 2
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('https://www.boxofficemojo.com/year/2020/?ref_=bo_yl_table_1')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait
while i < 269:
    wait
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="table"]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[{}]/td[2]/a'.format(i)).click()
    wait
    get_movie_dict(driver.current_url)
    wait
    i += 1
    wait
    driver.back()
```

I receive the followed errors:

```
ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    156             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 157                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
    158             )

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     83     if err is not None:
---> 84         raise err
     85 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     73                 sock.bind(source_address)
---> 74             sock.connect(sa)
     75             return sock

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    671                 headers=headers,
--> 672                 chunked=chunked,
    673             )

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    375         try:
--> 376             self._validate_conn(conn)
    377         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    993         if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 994             conn.connect()
    995 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in connect(self)
    299         # Add certificate verification
--> 300         conn = self._new_conn()
    301         hostname = self.host

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    168             raise NewConnectionError(
--> 169                 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
    170             )

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f42d8fec710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    719             retries = retries.increment(
--> 720                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
    721             )

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    435         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 436             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    437 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.boxofficemojo.comhttps', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl1182631425/?ref_=bo_yld_table_1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f42d8fec710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-0dd26218976b> in <module>
      9     driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="table"]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[{}]/td[2]/a'.format(i)).click()
     10     wait
---> 11     get_movie_dict(driver.current_url)
     12     wait
     13     i += 1

<ipython-input-45-2533561becb9> in get_movie_dict(link)
     19     wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
     20     wait
---> 21     response = requests.get(url)
     22     wait
     23     page = response.text

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     73 
     74     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 75     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     76 
     77 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     58     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     59     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 60         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     61 
     62 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    531         }
    532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    534 
    535         return resp

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Send the request
--> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
--> 516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    517 
    518         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.boxofficemojo.comhttps', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl1182631425/?ref_=bo_yld_table_1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f42d8fec710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Edit: Added the function `get_movie_dict`:

```
def get_movie_dict(link):
    '''
    From BoxOfficeMojo link stub, request movie html, parse with BeautifulSoup, and
    collect 
        - title 
        - domestic gross
        - runtime 
        - MPAA rating
        - full release date
    Return information as a dictionary.
    '''
    
    base_url = 'https://www.boxofficemojo.com'
    
    #Create full url to scrape
    url = base_url + link
    
    #Request HTML and parse
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait
    response = requests.get(url)
    wait
    page = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"lxml")

    
    headers = ['movie_title', 'domestic_total_gross',
               'runtime_minutes', 'rating', 'release_date', 'budget']
    
    #Get title
    title_string = soup.find('title').text
    title = title_string.split('-')[0].strip()
    #Get domestic gross
    try:
        raw_domestic_total_gross = (soup.find(class_='mojo-performance-summary-table')
                                    .find_all('span', class_='money')[0]
                                    .text
                               )
    except:
        raw_domestic_total_gross = float("NaN")
    
    if type(raw_domestic_total_gross) == float or type(raw_domestic_total_gross) == 'NoneType':
        print('This is NaN')
        domestic_total_gross = float("NaN")
    else:
        domestic_total_gross = money_to_int(raw_domestic_total_gross)

    #Get runtime
    raw_runtime = get_movie_value(soup,'Running')
    if type(raw_runtime) != float and type(raw_runtime) != 'NoneType':
        runtime = runtime_to_minutes(raw_runtime)
    
    #Get rating
    rating = get_movie_value(soup,'MPAA')

    #Get release date
    if '-' in get_movie_value(soup, 'Release Date'):
        raw_release_date = get_movie_value(soup,'Release Date').split('-')[0]
    elif '(' in get_movie_value(soup, 'Release Date'):
        raw_release_date = get_movie_value(soup,'Release Date').split('(')[0]
    else:
        raw_release_date = get_movie_value(soup,'Release Date').split('(')[0]
    release_date = to_date(raw_release_date)
    


    # Get budget alt 
    raw_budget = get_movie_value(soup,'Budget')
    budget = money_to_int(raw_budget)

    #Create movie dictionary and return
    movie_dict = dict(zip(headers,[title,
                                domestic_total_gross,
                                runtime,
                                rating, 
                                release_date,
                                budget]))

    return movie_dict
```

Comment: The error is in the function `get_movie_dict` that you have not added to the question

Comment: You're right, thanks. Added the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was. After removing this block from `get_movie_dict` the function worked properly:

```
#Request HTML and parse
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait
response = requests.get(url)
wait
page = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"lxml")
```

`get_movie_dict` is a helper function. The line with `response = requests.get(url)` was attempting to send another, unrelated GET request inside the helper function, which was unnecessary because one had already been sent outside of it - this is what was causing the problem.

This is an example of why it's important to understand what each line of code is doing, before copying and pasting it into your own code.

Answer (score 0):

The `link` that you are extracting from the page is "absolute" (it includes the scheme and hostname), when you add this to `base_url` you are getting a string that looks like `https://www.boxofficemojo.comhttps://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl1182631425/?ref_=bo_yld_table_1`

You should use [`urljoin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) to join the base url with the extracted url as it will handle both relative and absolute urls.

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
url = urljoin(base_url, link)
```